# How to remove content between two special character in js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a string data like below...

```
var myData = "<td>{{binding}}</td>"; //Here special character > and <
//My expected out: "<td></td>"
```

Comment: Parse the string, empty it's `innerHTML` and get the `outerHTML` of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
var myData = "<td>{{binding}}</td>";
var strippedData = myData.replace(/>[^<]+</g,"><");
```

I would recommend using `[^<]` instead of `.` to match the inner content so that you don't match more than what you want.  Also, by using + instead of * the regular expression will only match the places where there is actually content between `>` and `<`.

The `g` at the end of the regular expression is used to match and replace all of the occurrences.

Comment: Kruege, I have another problem which is like "<tr style='width:25px;' data-ng-repeat="store in stores"><td></td><tr>" My expected output will be  "<tr style='width:25px;'><td></td><tr>" What should I do?

Comment: @AminUddin in that case I would use something like myData.replace(/ data-ng-repeat="[^"]*"/g,"").  This will match the attribute and replace it with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.prototype.replace()` method with regular expressions.
Something like this:

```
var myData = "<td>{{binding}}</td>";
myData.replace(/>.*</, '><');
```

Comment: Thanks, If my input is   <tr data-ng-repeat="store in stores">
 <td style="width: 30%;">{{ store.customer }}</td>
  <td style="width: 20%;">{{ store.quantity }}</td>
            </tr>Then I get out put is  <tr data-ng-repeat="store in stores">
<td style="width: 30%;"></td>
                <td style="width: 30%;">{{ store.order }}</td>
              
            </tr>But My expected output like below: <tr data-ng-repeat="store in stores">
                <td style="width: 30%;"></td>
                <td style="width: 30%;"></td>
              
            </tr>